# How to interact with cffi void pointers inside numba

Tags: python, numba, cffi

I have a C library, which gets interfaced with CFFI as with the following definitions:

```py
import cffi
ffi = cffi.FFI()

ffi.cdef("""
typedef struct zkdtree  zkdtree;
typedef struct zkdtree_result zkdtree_result;


zkdtree * zkdtree_load(const char * filename, char ** errout);

void zkdtree_delete(zkdtree *);

size_t zkdtree_nfeatures(zkdtree *);

double zkdtree_interpolate(zkdtree *, double * pt);

zkdtree_result * zkdtree_result_allocate(void);

void zkdtree_result_delete(zkdtree_result *);

void zkdtree_point_info(zkdtree *, double * pt, zkdtree_result * output);

bool zkdtree_result_interpolable(zkdtree_result *);

double zkdtree_result_central_value(zkdtree_result *);

double zkdtree_result_variance(zkdtree_result *);

""")
```

Note that the internal structure of things like `zkdtree` is never referenced.

For the moment I am loading a dynamic library that contains the corresponding symbols:

```
C = ffi.dlopen("libcapi.so")
```

I would like to be able to call these functions inside a numba jitted function (in nopython mode) and trade the various anonymous structures (like zkdtree). I have seen the module `numba.cffi_support` but don't seem to know how to teach it to understand my definitions.

I have tried unsuccessfully with various variations around

```py
tree_load = C.zkdtree_load
err = ffi.new('char **')
interp = C.zkdtree_interpolate
cffi_support.register_type(ffi.typeof(tree), numba.void)


@numba.njit
def test_one_point():
    tree = tree_load(b"nlo.tree", err)
    interp(tree, [0.,0.,0.,0.])
```

but I have not been able to get it to work with both `tree` and `err`. I get errors like

```
TypeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
<ctype 'zkdtree'>
```